# Spring MVC 3 - Reload Property File with help of Standard Environment and Property Source

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

1. I am trying to achieve Reload properties file using spring MVC 3 without restarting the server.
2. And with the Below code I am able to reload the property file but if I access property value by `@Value` annotation, I am getting old value and if access value using `env.getProperty("key")`, I am getting updated value. What could be wrong?
3. Question: does `PropertySource` and `StandardEnvironment` hold property values separately in memory?

```java
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:static_resources.properties")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public class RefreshEnvironmentPropertyController {

        @Autowired protected StandardEnvironment environment;

        @Value("${prop-test}") String propTest; 

        @RequestMapping(value = "refresh", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String refreshProperty() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("propTest\t"+ propTest);
            System.out.println("env-propTest\t"+ environment.getProperty("prop-test"));

            MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("/static_resources.properties").getPath()));
            InputStream inputStream = inputStream1;
            properties.load(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            mutablePropertySources.replace("class path resource [static_resources.properties]",
                    new PropertiesPropertySource("class path resource [static_resources.properties]", properties));
            System.out.println("propTest\t"+ propTest);
            System.out.println("env-propTest\t"+ environment.getProperty("prop-test"));
            return "refreshed";
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Found the solution:- Follow as below**

```
<bean id="messageSource" 
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1"/>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/refresh")
public class RefreshResourceController {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RefreshResourceController.class);

    @Autowired
    protected ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = "refresh-static-resource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String refreshProperty() {
        log.info("request reached..");
        try {
            bundleMessageSource.clearCache();
            return "SUCCESS";
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            log.error("RefreshResourceController:refreshProperty() ", e);
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```